# how to make jjoe64 graphview scrollable

Tags: android

My xml is

```
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/graph_view" />
```

and the code

```
graphView = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph_view);
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]
            {
                new DataPoint(0, 1),

                new DataPoint(2, 3),

                new DataPoint(4, 6),

                new DataPoint(6, 9),

                new DataPoint(8, 9),

                new DataPoint(10, 9),

                new DataPoint(12, 1) ,

                new DataPoint(14, 9),




    });

    graphView.addSeries(series);
    StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graphView);
    staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"0", "2", "4","6", "8", "10","12", "14", "16","18", "20", "22","24"});
    staticLabelsFormatter.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"0", "2", "4","6","8","10","12"});
    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
    graphView.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
    graphView.getViewport().isScrollable();
    graphView.getViewport().scrollToEnd();
```

I want to know how i set the horizontal scroll because the x-axis level are so close to each other and the ui is very bad.Can anyone help to findout the solution...

Comment: Are there any possibilities for using Java variables instead of defining numbers directly? (x1, y1) instead of (1, 2) ???

Answer (score 4):

Add this code below after defining your graph:

```
GraphView graphView = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graphView);  //defining your graph as GraphView

graphView.getViewport().setScalable(true);  // activate horizontal zooming and scrolling
graphView.getViewport().setScrollable(true);  // activate horizontal scrolling
graphView.getViewport().setScalableY(true);  // activate horizontal and vertical zooming and scrolling
graphView.getViewport().setScrollableY(true);  // activate vertical scrolling
```